# Delete auth user in firebase react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to delete auth user from firebase with email or uid. I searched on google but I did not find any solution.

Comment: Are you trying to delete user as an admin or trying to add an option where user can delete their own account?

Comment: i am trying to delete user as an admin

Answer (score 4):

For React Native

```js
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

 let user = auth().currentUser;
    user
      .delete()
      .then(() => console.log("User deleted"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a code section:

```
getAuth()
  .deleteUser(uid)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

Additionally reference link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: when i type getAuth() don't give me deleteUser

Comment: and give this warning [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.auth.deleteUser is not a function. (In '_firebase.auth.deleteUser(item.uid)', '_firebase.auth.deleteUser' is undefined)]

Answer (score 1):

I found this method, but this deletes current user, I want to delete the specific user.

```
import { getAuth, deleteUser } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

deleteUser(user).then(() => {
// User deleted.
}).catch((error) => {
// An error ocurred
// ...
});
```